# ERROR:Deploying Python app using heroku CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

When I enter

> $ git push heroku master

It Shows:

> ERROR: Double requirement given: telegram (from -r /tmp/build_996aa7e0/requirements.txt (line 60)) (already in telegram==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_996aa7e0/requirements.txt (line 47)), name='telegram')

There is the All logs:

> Enumerating objects: 8, done.
>
> Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 7.00 KiB | 716.00 KiB/s, done.
>
> Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
>
> remote: Compressing source files... done.
>
> remote: Building source:
>
> remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
>
> remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
>
> remote: -----> Python app detected
>
> remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.13
>
> remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
>
> remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
>
> remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
>
> remote:        ERROR: Double requirement given: telegram (from -r /tmp/build_996aa7e0/requirements.txt (line 60)) (already in telegram==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_996aa7e0/requirements.txt (line 47)), name='telegram')
>
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
>
> remote:  !     Push failed
>
> remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 084ac888b168cf47da1ece8fd2b17b05e1d4df48
>
> remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 084ac888b168cf47da1ece8fd2b17b05e1d4df48
> remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
>
> remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
>
> remote:  !     git push heroku :main
>
> remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
>
> remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
>
> remote: Verifying deploy...
>
> remote: !       Push rejected to zsk766.
>
> remote: To https://git.heroku.com/zsk766.git

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got `telegram` twice in your requirements.txt, once at line 60 and once at line 47.

Open `requirements.txt`, delete one of those lines, and repush your files.